# Is there a way to create table of content automatically for a PDF file?

Tags: pdf

I have a long PDF file without ToC. I can manually created them but it is tedious. Is there any automatic approach? Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to create your PDF? We can't help you if you don't tell us. There is a solution for MS Office, LibreOffice, LaTeX and basically any software.

Comment: I am not the creator of the PDF. The PDF is not secured and I can modify it. I am OK with any solution as long as it can create ToC.

Comment: You might look at the Debenu Aerialist plug-in, which should be able to do what you want to accomplish.